# Como Dividir Carpeta? en python

Tags: python, split

Buenas Tardes. 
 Tengo una carpeta (directorio) con muchos archivos (mas de 25000) y necesito dividir esa carpeta en sub-carpetas de que contengan 500 archivos cada una.

-el criterio para dividir los archivos puede ser por orden alfabetico, por tamaño, por fecha de creación, al azar etc.
-las carpetas creadas pueden tener cualquier nombre.

¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo realizarlo?

Espero se haya entendido la preguntita.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Carlos. Dos aclaraciones, ¿necesitas que las carpetas que se creen se nombren de alguna forma especial? Por otro lado ¿Con que criterio metes cada archivo en cada subcarpeta? ¿O simplemente deseas que por orden alfabetico, por ejemplo, se metan en carpetas de 500 archivos y que estas se nombren 'Carpeta 1', 'Carpeta 2', etc?

Comment: Las carpetas pueden tener cualquier nombre.
Y si, puede ser por orden alfabetico ,  por orden de tamaño o fecha de creacion, el criterio da lo mismo. 

Como los planteas tu está perfecto.

Gracias por la Bienvenida.

Comment: Carlos, ahora que formas parte de la comunidad, me gustaría invitarte a que hicieras el [tour] del sitio y sobre todo a que editaras tu pregunta siguiendo la guía [help/mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
import os

path = "yourpath"
count = 0
factor = 500 # numero de archivos por carpeta
curren_dir = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if count % factor == 0:
            curren_dir = "{path}/subdirectory{count}".format(path=path,
                                                             count=int(count / factor))
            os.mkdir(curren_dir)
        os.rename("{path}/{file}".format(path=path, file=file),
                  "{path}/{file}".format(path=curren_dir, file=file))
        count += 1
```

Comment: Excelente, Super útil!

Answer (score 1):

Este código te puede servir para empezar, tienes que mezclarlo con tu criterios. El pequeño ejemplo crea dos carpetas(carpetanueva2 y Ejemplo) esto lo realiza en el directorio donde esta el archivo python además la carpeta Ejemplo la mueve hacia dentro de “carpetanueva2” para el caso movimos la carpeta pero tu le puedes poner el archivo que deseas mover y lo moverá.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, shutil

os.system("mkdir carpetanueva2") #Crea una carpeta llamada 'carpetanueva' en el actual directorio
os.system("mkdir Ejemplo") #Crea una carpeta llamada 'carpetanueva' en el actual directorio

shutil.move("Ejemplo", "./carpetanueva2") #Movera la carpeta "Ejemplo" dentro de "carpetanueva2"
```

Saludos, si quedan dudas comentalo y te puedo seguir ayudando.